# audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError in librosa

Tags: python, librosa

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import IPython.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

audio_path = 'rec.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
```

I tried to load the audio file into librosa.
So I wrote the code like that.
But I get the error "File contains data in an unknown format", "File contains data in an unknown format".

I searched on Google and I was told to install ffmpeg.
So I installed ffmpeg but still get the error

What's wrong?
(I guess there is a problem with the encoding.........)

all error messege:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 129, in load
    with sf.SoundFile(path) as sf_desc:
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1184, in _open
    "Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1357, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'rec.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/pitch_project_/pitdetec.py", line 12, in <module>
    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 147, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 171, in __audioread_load
    with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py", line 116, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError
```

try:

```
audio_path = 'C:/Users/ddolcju/PycharmProjects/pitch_project/rec.mp3'
```

Comment: I found that installing *librosa* via miniconda gives the best results and usually avoids the missing library issues.

Comment: Thank you, but problem was not solved.

Answer (score 10):

There are few things you need to check:

1. `librosa` can't read mp3 files directly so it tries to use the `audioread` package.
2. `Audioread` tries to utilise a number of different packages that may or may not be installed.  One of those is `ffmpeg`.
3. However it uses `FFmpeg` 'via its command-line interface'. I think this is the reason that `pip` installing FFmpeg doesn't work. It needs the `ffmpeg.exe` file.
4. You can download the `ffmpeg` [installer from here](https://ffmpeg.org/)
5. After it is installed make sure you can start `ffmpeg` from the command line (type `ffmpeg -h`). You will probably need to add the path to the install folder (eg `c:\ffmpeg\bin`) to the Windows path.
6. Finally, make sure to restart your IDE. Visual Studio Code probably won't recognise the new path until after a reset.

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu  I resolved it by following command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

`pip install ffmpeg` did not worked for me

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Installing `ffmpeg` in Ubuntu `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 ` indeed solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem on windows 10, after installing ffmpeg and configuring it to PATH, it works. Need restart a python session.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you solved your problem, but if anyone else has this problem:

I installed ffmpeg (the following code) and it worked.

```
pip install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

- wav files should be supported natively, according to https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/219
- mp3 on the other hand requires a backend, e.g. ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and the issue was that I had only partially downloaded the targetted `.wav` file and it was therefore corrupted. Once I re-downloaded the file and tried again it worked fine. The error was a bit misleading in my case because the backend was available and working. As such, if none of the suggestions here work, try loading your target file in a music player to confirm its veracity.